# Joomla custom fields in mod_articles_category

Tags: custom-field, mod-articles-category, joomla3.8.5

i've create several custom fields and i can show all them easy in articles, or articles list.

Now i would need render them in mod_articles_category override but i cannot reach the target so far.

Is it possible in some way?

Answer (score 1):

Because it is in a module it will not understand the context.

Usually the fields are called by checking the article id from the menu item, but as it is a module, it does not have a menu item or an article id.

So you need to find the article ID for each particular article.  Then call it that way.

Here you can find out how to get the fields renderer to work:
https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Adding_custom_fields/Overrides

Someone seems to have it working correctly here:
https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=954346

If you can't get that working put your code in your question and any error messages you see (set error reporting to maximum) and then you give people the best chance to help you.